# Showing pop-up window with content from console output

Tags: html, ajax, spring-boot, popup

So I have this form where the user enters certain values for fields and based on the user's input I am performing scp and ftp of certain files. As this process takes around 2-3 minutes, the result page takes that amount of time to load.

What I want to do is to open up a pop-up window after the user clicks on submit and display the contents of console output in that pop-up and display the result page only after it has loaded completely. The console output has some useful info that the user can see to check the progress and this will also make the web application more responsive.

How do I go about this?

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pmruploadform", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String pmrUploadForm()
{
    return "uploadpage";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/pmrupload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String pmrUpload(@RequestParam("tool") String tool, @RequestParam("data") String data, @RequestParam("pmrid") String pmrid, @RequestParam("issue") String issue, @RequestParam("envt") String envt, @RequestParam("emailid") String emailid, ModelMap model) throws IOException
{

    Pmr pmr = new Pmr();
    pmr.setPmrId(pmrid);
    pmr.setTool(tool);
    pmr.setData(data);
    pmr.setIssue(issue);
    pmr.setHostenv(envt);

    String host = null;
    List<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(pmr.getTool().equals("udeploy"))
    {
        switch(pmr.getHostenv())
        {
            case("dev"):
                host = udHostConfig.getDev();
                hosts.add(host);
                break;
            case("stage"):
                hosts = udHostConfig.getStage();
                break;
            case("prod"):
                hosts = udHostConfig.getProd();
                break;
        }
    }

    if(pmr.getTool().equals("urelease"))
    {
        switch(pmr.getHostenv())
        {
            case("dev"):
                host = urHostConfig.getDev();
                hosts.add(host);
                break;
            case("stage"):
                hosts = urHostConfig.getStage();
                break;
            case("prod"):
                hosts = urHostConfig.getProd();
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(pmrBaseDir);
    PmrUploadService.uploadService(hosts,pmrid,pmrBaseDir,emailid,tool);//This is the call that takes 2-3 mins. to execute and where the console output is printed
    pmrRepository.insert(pmr);

    int i,j,k;
    char[] pmrc1=new char[5];
    char[] pmrc2=new char[5];
    char[] pmrc3=new char[5];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        pmrc1[i]=pmrid.charAt(i);
    i++;
    for(j=0;i<9;i++,j++)
        pmrc2[j]=pmrid.charAt(i);
    i++;
    for(k=0;i<13;i++,k++)
        pmrc3[k]=pmrid.charAt(i);

    String pmr1=new String(pmrc1);
    String pmr2=new String(pmrc2);
    String pmr3=new String(pmrc3);

    model.addAttribute("pmrlink",pmrlink);
    model.addAttribute("tool", tool);
    model.addAttribute("data", data);
    model.addAttribute("pmrid", pmrid);
    model.addAttribute("issue", issue);
    return "resultpage";

}
```

Here is the uploadpage jsp:

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Upload Data</h1>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Enter File Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <form role="form" action="pmrupload.html" method="POST" name="myForm">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Enter PMR Number</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="pmrid">
                                                <p class="help-block">Format = XXXXX.YYY.ZZZ</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Select Tool</label>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="udeploy">uDeploy
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="urelease">uRelease
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Select Data</label>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="log">Logs
                                                    </label>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="thread dump">Thread dump
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="diagnostics">Diagnostics
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Select Environment</label>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="envt" value="dev">Dev
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="envt" value="stage">Stage
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="envt" value="prod">Prod
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Enter Email ID</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="emailid">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Issue</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="issue">
                                            </div>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.panel-body -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
```

Here is the result jsp:

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Result</h1>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                     <p>Success! File Uploaded Successfully</p>
                     <p>Tool: ${tool}</p>                     
         <p>Data: ${data}</p>
         <p>PMR id: ${pmrid}</p>
         <p>Issue: ${issue}</p>
         <!-- /.panel -->
                     <a href="${pmrlink}">Click here to see uploaded PMR</a>
                     
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code:

```
var output ='here is the output that you got';
onload = function myFunction() {
   var myform = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=400,height=300");
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML = "<h1>Title</h1><div>this is a content from "+output+"</div>";
   myform.document.body.append(div);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to write on the browser console, I want to display the java output in the pop-up window. Also, calling the function after the page loads serves no purpose. I want the pop-up to display in parallel while the result page loads.

Comment: This code displays the pop-up after the page has loaded, I want the pop-up while the page loads..

Comment: If so, you just remove onload and call this function at the point that you want to call.